# Helvetica Neue Light,iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, fonts

Surprisingly I can't seem to find another question on this... sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

I'm trying to use Helvetica Neue Light programatically in my iPhone app. It seems that the system doesn't have this built in, which seems strange.

Is this the case? Does this particular font need to be added manually?

Ideally I'd like to edit this line of code to accomplish this:

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size: 32];
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The font name you used is incorrect, try:

**Objective-C**

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:32.0f];
```

**Swift**

```
myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 32.0)
```

On [iOS Fonts](http://iosfonts.com/) you will find the full list of fonts and their names.

Comment: HelveticaNeue just use for regular font @NSPratik

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE FOR SWIFT 3**

For the past few month, swift approach towards `init` has changed, I would recommend not to use `init` in Swift 3

`label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 17.0)`

> **Objective- C :**
>
> ```
> [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17.0f]];
> ```
>
> **Swift 2.2 :**
>
> ```
> label.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 17.0)
> ```

**UPDATE :**

This has worked for me. Write this code below your label declarations.

It sets all the **UILabel** under a function with same font.

**Objective-C :**

```
[[UILabel appearance]setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:32.0f]];
```

**Swift 2.2 :**

```
UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 32.0)
```

To set font to particular **UILabel** use this code :

**Objective-C :**

```
[labelName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:15.0f]];
```

**Swift 2.2 :**

```
label.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 17.0)
```

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://iosfonts.com) is a link where all the supported fonts are available for iOS.

*HelveticaNeue* is supported in iOS and its Keyword is **"HelveticaNeue"**

Comment: The OP asked about Helvetica Neue Light.

Answer (score 0):

I have one suggestion if you like to use UIFont please print all the font names.  so in future you will always get correct font name.

You just need to paste method somewhere in you class and you will get the list of all system fonts

```
-(void)fontNames{

    NSArray *familyNames = [UIFont familyNames];
    [familyNames enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        NSLog(@"* %@",obj);
        NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:obj];
        [fontNames enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
            NSLog(@"--- %@",obj);
        }];
    }];  

}
```

Comment: This is very helpful addition.